# Retrieve image from Amazon S3 private bucket using Node JS

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-s3

I am using Node JS for one of my website. As per requirement of website I am using Amazon S3 to store image in the bucket.

I am using API to upload image dynamically in my Amazon S3 Bucket using access key and secretases key.

But now I want to preview or display those uploaded images(not all at once) in website using node JS. Please note that S3 bucket is not public.

Can anyone please suggest how to retrieve the image from Amazon S3 using Node JS?
Have tried with using getObject(),Getting 403 forbidden error. File successfully uploading into S3 bucket, While reading the file not able to see the uploaded file due to forbidden error.

Here is My code

```
let fileNew = request.file;
        if (!fileNew) {
            response.status(200).json({ message: "Failure, please upload file", status: 400 });
        }
        const params = {
            Bucket: aws_s3_bucketName,
            Key: fileNew.originalname,
            Body: fileNew.buffer,
        };
        
        s3.upload(params, async function (err: any, data: any) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log("There was an error while uploading your file: ", err.message);
            }
            const fileInfo =data.Location;
            response.status(200).json({ message: "Success", data: fileInfo , status: 200 });
        });
        s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err){
                console.log(err, err.stack);
            }  
            else {
                console.log(data); 
            }              
    });
```

Comment: make sure the iam role you're using has s3:GetObject permission

Comment: @AmanB,Yeah it has the permission

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the upload and download happens in different requests.

In this case:
If you are using the exact same identity for PUT and GET, then it should work. If you want to allow others in the AWS account to access the objects, then add the `bucket-owner-full-control` `ACL` when you upload.

```
const params = {
  Bucket: aws_s3_bucketName,
  Key: fileNew.originalname,
  Body: fileNew.buffer,
  ACL: 'bucket-owner-full-control'
};
```

More information about ACL [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html)

If you want to download the file as soon as it gets uploaded, then move the download block into the callback of the upload function.

Comment: ,Updated with ACL,but still i'm getting 403 Forbidden error

Comment: Can you confirm if you are using the exact same credentials for both the operations. Add the S3 bucket policy and the IAM permission policy of the identity you are using to invoke the apis. Verify if there are any SCP for your organisation. Verify if the IAM identity is having any role boundaries.

Comment: Yes I'm using same credentials for both operations, we have the authorization token policy in my application. Have added S3 bucket policies and IAM permissions. If I make it S3 bucket as Public it's working fine without any issues, Facing issue when my bucket make it as Private.

Comment: Check out this https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/ If this does not help, recommend raising a support ticket with AWS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awssupport/latest/user/case-management.html

Comment: I have tried to using amazon documentation, But it's not helping me out.